# UITests Xcode7: How to adjust date picker with multiply pickers?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-ui-testing

On the screen I have `UIDatePicker`. It would be simple if there was simple picker. It could be like that:

```
app.pickeWheels["my_id_picker"].adjustToPickerWheelValue("expected_value")
```

but the question is how to adjust multiply pickers within `UIDatePicker`?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You will have to access the different wheels by specifying what element/component of the picker you want to adjust.

Here is my code (in Swift 2.2) with a much simpler date picker but I believe you can adjust the code to meet your needs:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let date = NSDate()
let month = calendar.component(NSCalendarUnit.Month, fromDate: date)
let day = calendar.component(NSCalendarUnit.Day, fromDate: date)
let nextMonthName = dateFormatter.monthSymbols[month]

let firstWheel = app.pickerWheels.elementBoundByIndex(0)
firstWheel.adjustToPickerWheelValue("\(nextMonthName)")

let secondWheel = app.pickerWheels.elementBoundByIndex(1)
secondWheel.adjustToPickerWheelValue("\(day+1)")
```

Comment: Nice solution!  I'm puzzled that the date picker has to be referred to as a general picker.  I tried app.datePickers.element(boundBy: 2) and got this error: No matches for datePicker

Comment: I would have to look into it but I am assuming its because you can't really refer to UIElements per se when UITesting. They are just XCElements. I would be glad to see some type of reference to the ui elements but I also get why it doesn't exist. I think thats not the purpose of UITests. I try to pretend I am a user swiping through the app when I right my tests :)